# why i can not cast parent to child some specific scenario

Tags: java, inheritance, types, casting, polymorphism

I have two classes, one Animal and one Bear.
example code

```
class Animal {}
class Bear extends Animal {}
```

when I write code like

```
Animal animal = new Bear();
Bear bear = (Bear) animal;
```

I also know that the first one is upcasting and second one is downcasting and works fine.

but my question is when I code like:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Bear bear = (Bear) animal;
```

it throughs a `ClassCastException`.

I want to know why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Casting in Java can't change an object type. It just tells the compiler that it's OK to treat a certain object as a certain type, since in runtime that's what's going to be there.

In the first example, `bear` is really a `Bear` instance, so the casting works just fine.
In the second example, it isn't, so you get a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1):

If the 23rd method of type `Bear` is `growl`, and `bear` is the 5th local variable in a function, a Java compiler will translate `bear.growl()` to "Execute method #23 of local variable #5".  Such a translation would be good if the object was in fact an instance of class `Bear` or a derived type were method #23 was `growl()`, but could be disastrous if the reference were of some type which didn't have `growl()` as method #23.  While the JVM might be able to catch such issues at function invocation time if the object didn't have a method #23, it would be unlikely to catch them if the object was e.g. a `Dragon` whose method #23 was `breatheFire()`.  Rather than requiring that every attempt to use method `growl` on a variable of type `Bear` check to ensure that the object actually has `growl` as method #23, Java forbids storing any reference where method #23 isn't `growl` into a variable of type `bear`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Bear bear = (Bear) animal;
```

This is because your parent class doesn't know about your child's properties and methods.
In the first line you are simply creating an **animal** object, that's all. If you want to cast this animal reference, you must assign the child object to that, so that your parent reference is aware of child's properties and methods too.
This must be replaced with

```
Animal animal = new Bear();
Bear bear = (Bear) animal;
```